# Parsing XML string using XSLT

Tags: xslt, decoding

I have an XML document that has a TextBlock that contains HTML code.

```
<TextBlock>
  <h1>This is a header.</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</TextBlock>
```

In the actual XML, however, it is coded like this:

```
<TextBlock>
  &lt;h1&gt;This is a header.&lt;/h1&gt;
  &lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;
</TextBlock>
```

So when I use `<xsl:value-of select="TextBlock"/>` it displays all of the coding on the page. Is there a way using XSLT to convert `&lt;` to `<` within the TextBlock element?

Comment: Why? This is the same as treating unparsed data as parseable data. Don't, please! Also, this is not encode/decode issue but parsing...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you ask why? The XML is using `&lt;` and not `<`, so my data is not displaying correctly. Why would I want that code showing on the page? The solution below fixes my problem, except in Firefox which doesn't support DOE, unless there is a better solution out there.

Comment: You wrote: *The XML is using [...]*. That's no true. The document author is using that, instead.

Comment: Sure. I suppose. I have no control over what the XML or the author of the XML uses. I have to work with what I have, so either way it doesn't really matter. My question still remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="TextBlock" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

and the result:

```
<h1>This is a header.</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Firefox has a corresponding bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168, which contains a lot of comments and is an interesting reading.

I am looking for a fix now.

**EDIT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="disable-output-escaping.xsl"/> 
    <!-- https://bug98168.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=434081 -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/TextBlock">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="disable-output-escaping"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When inspecting via Firebug, the result looks correct:

```
<textblock>
    <h1>This is a header.</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</textblock>
```

Comment: I honestly tried that before, but I must have been placing it in the wrong place in the code. Thank you!

Comment: One problem, it seems to be working in Chrome, IE, & Safari, but not in Firefox. When I view it in FF, it still displays all the coding `<h1>This is a header.</h1><p>This is a paragraph.</p>` on the page. Any clue why?

Comment: @jrottier: I think, FF's XSLT processor doesn't support DOE. This is the trouble with DOE that it is not a mandatory XSLT feature. In XPath 3.0 there may be a function `parse()` with exactly this use-case in mind.

Comment: @jrottier, @Dimitre, see the link in my update, it is really worth reading.

Comment: Duh. It doesn't even work with CDATA and actual "<",">" instead of "lt","gt".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you last comment. Is there an alternative to DOE in Firefox?

Comment: There is an XSLT solution https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=434081, but it is rather heavy due to a lot of string work. You can try it though.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to incorporate that solution into my current XSL document. Where does it go in the document? Or where would my code go in that document?

Comment: @jrottier, see the update. Still it's an awkward solution unfortunately.

Comment: @Flack Great! Thank you for taking the time to help me out! I really appreciate it.